# if G does not have vertices of odd degree, then there are disjoints cycles by edges

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Show that if G does not have vertices of odd degree, then there are disjoints cycles by edges $C_{1}, C_{2}, C_{3},...C_{m}$ such that

$E(G)=E(C_{1}) \cup E(C_{2})\cup ...\cup...\cup E(C_{M})$

I think this problem is solved by Hamiltonian graphics, but I can't show it 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Thinking in terms of Eulerian cycles may be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a graph, If $G$ does not have vertices of odd degree, then $G$ cannot be a tree and hence contains a cycle. Now we prove by induction of $|E(G)|$ than $E(G)$ can decomposed as disjoint union of circles.

Base case: $|E(G)|=2$ is trivial to check. 
Now, Take a connected component $Co_1$ of $G$, $Co_1$ has a circle $C_1$ by previous reasoning. Now, $G-|E(C_1)|$'s edges can be decomposed as disjoint union of circles $C_2,...C_n$ by induction hypothesis, Well those circles together with $C_1$ form a disjoint union of circles for $E(G)$. Done.

Here is the proof from some notes.

[image]

Comment: The base case in your post is incorrect.  The base case should be |E(G)|=0.